# Elasticsearch.net NEST cannot filter on URL

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I am running an app basically creating a URL shortener and when I setup the "shorurl" which is upper and lower case I cannot get a Query or a Filter to find it.  However for other fields that are more simple it works just fine.  I tried doing lower case on it not sure really how to match.

Here is the field definition:

```
       [ElasticProperty(Name = "shorturl", IncludeInAll = true)]
        public string ShortUrl { get; set; }
```

Here is an example:

```
        string url = "http://test.com/JjdWtPoV";

        FilterContainer filter = new FilterContainer();
        filter = Filter<Data>.Term("shorturl", url);

        var results = this.Client.Search<Data>(s => s
            .Filter(filter)
        );

        QueryContainer q = new QueryContainer();
        q = Query<Data>.Term("shorturl", url);

        results = this.Client.Search<Data>(s => s
            .Query(q)
        );

        results = this.Client.Search<Data>(s => s
            .Query(f => f.Term(p=> p.ShortUrl, url))
        );
```

I should note the following is what versions I'm using:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <packages>
          <package id="Elasticsearch.Net" version="1.3.1" targetFramework="net45" />
          <package id="NEST" version="1.3.1" targetFramework="net45" />
          <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
        </packages>
```

**FOUND THE ANSWER**
Need to ensure a string has "NOT ANALYZED" set

```
        [ElasticProperty(Name = "shorturl", IncludeInAll = true,                          
                    Index=FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]
        public string ShortUrl { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   [ElasticProperty(Name = "shorturl", IncludeInAll = true,                          
                Index=FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]
    public string ShortUrl { get; set; }
```

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what is going on in your code, to help others.
How does this work exactly?

Comment: @Mohamadshiralizadeh `string` fields by default will be analyzed using the `standard` analyzer which will, amongst other things, lowercase tokens generated from the input when storing them in the inverted index. A terms query/filter does not analyze the query input, so there's a mismatch between the query input and the indexed input in terms of analsis (not analyzed vs. analyzed, respectively). If you want to do term(s) queries on a field, might also want to store as `not_analyzed`, either the field directly (as in this case), or map it as a `multi_field` with a `not_analyzed` sub-field